# C++ array overflow

Tags: arrays, overflow

I want to know why the first main doesnt crash while running, but the second main actually crash while it was running.

```
int main(){
    int a[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 70; i++){
        cout << i << "=" << a[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main( ){
    int a[5];
    cout << a[6];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. No need to wonder more. It could do whatever.

Comment: what is an undefined behavior?

Comment: A behavior that hasn't been defined. The standard only defines what happens when accessing inside the array. If you access beyond it anything can happen and no specification says what. Crashing is just one option.

Answer (score 0):

You try to read outside the defined bounds of your array. The later is only defined from 0 to 4 (i.e. a[0] to a[4]).

What happens is undefined by the standard and is dependent of the compiler, the current memory state, etc. Both main could "work" one day and crash another day or not at all.

For undefined behaviour, the compiler can do whatever he wants.

In computer programming, undefined behavior (UB) is the result of executing computer code that does not have a prescribed behavior by the language specification the code adheres to, for the current state of the program (e.g. memory). This happens when the translator of the source code makes certain assumptions, but these assumptions are not satisfied during execution.

For more details, [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

As said @Sami Kuhmonen, both are wrong as you are accessing an array out of its boundaries. I can provide an hypothetic explanation  (as it depends on compiler, Operating system and even processor; and finding the true reason would need a too big effort for just a theorical knowledge benefit ): in the second main (), declaring "int i" allocates some more space on the stack, so the array can be read out of its boundaries without crashing.